# APA6 Class - Single-spaced Tables for Manuscript

Tags: tables, floats, line-spacing, apa6

I'm trying to produce a manuscript for submission. I have tables that are fairly long and need to be single spaced. The `apa6` class is double-spacing the entire document including the tables. I need double-spaced body text and single-spaced tables. My previous version of the document, before I tried `apa6`, invoked the `endfloat` package and the spacing was what I needed. As an aside, the `apa6` manual suggests tables can be either single or double spaced. Can I request this format from the class?

Comment: Hi Bob, [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043). If you include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/9043), i.e. a short document with a table and perhaps some dummy text with the [`lipsum`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lipsum/lipsum.pdf) package, other members of the community will be able to copy, paste and experiment with your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`apa6`](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6) does not a provide a float-specific spacing as a document class option (see section **3.1 Class Options** of the [`apa6` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/apa6/apa6.pdf), p 2). However, it loads the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) by default which provides `\AtBeginEnvironment{<env>}{<stuff>}` that hooks into and adds `<stuff>` at `\begin{<env>}`. So, you can use

```
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}% Single spacing in tabular environment
```

Although it is not necessary to load use the [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) interface for `\singlespacing` in this case, it is just for convenience. If you're not allowed to use `setspace`, you could also just use

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{%
  \def\baselinestretch{1}\@currsize}%
\makeatother
```

[image]

Here is a minimal example using the former `setspace` adjustment:

```
\documentclass[man,floatsintext]{apa6}% http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6
\shorttitle{Some title}% Dummy title
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
% Already loaded by the apa6 documentclass...
% \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}% Single spacing in tabular environment
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
    \toprule
    One & Two & Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven \\
    \midrule
    100 & 200 & 300 & 400 & 500 & 600 & 700 \\
    100 & 200 & 300 & 400 & 500 & 600 & 700 \\
    100 & 200 & 300 & 400 & 500 & 600 & 700 \\
    100 & 200 & 300 & 400 & 500 & 600 & 700 \\
    100 & 200 & 300 & 400 & 500 & 600 & 700 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is a table.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was merely used to create dummy text *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the SETSPACE command but got an error: ! Undefined control sequence.\@begin@tabular@hook ->\singlespacing \begin{tabular}. The second solution worked fine. I'm not yet very familiar with Latex programming, but I hope to learn. I deduce that your code is altering the Table class within the document. Does @currsize refer to an argument to the table class? --- Just curious. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @BobP: You should include the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) (via `\usepackage{setspace}`) for you to be able to use `\singlespacing`). The `\@currsize` macro is something that sets the current font size. If you look at [`setspace.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/setspace/setspace.sty), you'll see that I extracted the equivalent of `\singlespacing` from that file as a replacement. If this solved your problem, consider up-voting and/or accepting (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)).

Comment: I didn't realize that setspace was independent of etoolbox. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the apa6 class and its options, but you can do it manually with the following code. I suggest to create an environment which creates the table and formats the font, spacing and so on. These changes effects only the environment/table and switched back after leaving the environment.

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newenvironment{myTable}%
{%
    \footnotesize
    \singlespace
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1.5ex}
    % other formating stuff
    \begin{longtable}{p{5cm}p{5cm}p{5cm}}
    Column 1 &Column 2 &Column 3\\
    \hline
}%
{%
    \end{longtable}
}%


\doublespace
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{myTable}
    \lipsum[1]&\lipsum[1]&\lipsum[1]\\
\end{myTable}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The [`apa6` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/apa6/apa6.pdf) specifically mentions not loading [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) explicitly, but rather as a class option using `\documentclass[longtable]{apa6}`.